# Best power equipment to remove compacted gravel?

Tags: gravel

I have a gravel driveway in my front yard that I want to remove to put a garden bed. The gravel is large (1/2" to 1" dia.) and very compacted, so it is nearly impossible to remove by hand.

I want to rent some small power equipment to do the task, but I'm not sure if a skid loader, excavator, or something else is the right tool for the job. Opinions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Last time I rented a bobcat to dig out a compacted clay bank even with a toothed bucket it could not break up the clay.  Compacted gravel could be equally hard.

I recommend hiring a [backhoe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backhoe) which has a hydraulic bucket on the back.  Bonus is that the person/company owning the backhoe usually has a dump truck to pull a trailer.  You can get them to break and load the gravel into the truck in one operation.